# How to use same beans in Test Configuration but with different attributes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have separate configuration classes that creates different beans per `Spring Profile`. I want my tests to simulate production code as much as possible so I want to use the **same beans** created under the `Spring ‘PROD’ Profile` but add/update different attributes specifically used for testing. What is the best way to achieve that?

Example of what I mean:

```
@Profile(PROD)
public class ProdConfig {
    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory containerFactory() {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(2);
        ...
        return factory;
    }
}

@Profile(TEST)
public class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory containerFactory() {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(2);
        ...
        /**
            The advice chain should only set for testing purposes
        **/
        factory.setAdviceChain(interceptor());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    RetryOperationsInterceptor interceptor() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Ideally I don't want to duplicate the code to set various properties of `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` in `TestConfig`. I just want to load the ProdConfig but call `setAdviceChain(interceptor())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@Import(ProdConfig.class)
public class TestConfig {

    @Autowired
    private SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory containerFactory;

    @Bean
    RetryOperationsInterceptor interceptor() {
        ...

        this.containerFactory.setAdviceChain(interceptor);

        return interceptor;
    }

}
```